# Привязать событие click к контроллу который создан динамически ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, c#, html, jquery, angularjs

В блоке который заполняется при помощи ng-repeat есть блок

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12 main-block-history" ng-repeat="order in orders">
  <div class="row block-history-footer">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 action-accordion-history">
      <a>Развернуть</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row block-history-body" style="display: none; opacity: 0;">
  </div>
</div>
```

После чего в контроллере отправляется post запрос и заполняется переменная $scope.orders и соответственно заполняется контент блока, но события не привязаны к блокам с классом action-accordion-history.

```
var app = angular.module('BlankApp', ['ngMaterial']);

app.controller('BlankAppController', function ($scope, $http) {

$http({
    url: "dirService",
    method: "post",
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        "dataType": "json"
    },
    data: "{ 'token': '" + getCookie("token") + "' }"
}).then(function (response) {
    $scope.orders = response.data.d;

    $('.action-accordion-history').on('click');
});
});

$(function () {

$(".action-accordion-history").click(function () {
    var block = $(this).parent().parent().find(".block-history-body");
    if (!block.is(":visible")) {
        block.show();
        block.stop().animate({
            opacity: 1
        }, 150);
        $(this).html("<a>Свернуть</a>");
    } else {
        block.stop().animate({
            opacity: 0
        }, 150, function () {
            block.hide();
        });
        $(this).html("<a>Развернуть</a>");
    }
});
});
```

Как быть. Как привязать событие click к созданным блокам с классом action-accordion-history?
Проблема еще в том, если событие создавать при помощи ng-click у контролла, что в функцию надо передать ссылку на контролл на котом произошло событие, но я не нашел как это сделать.

Comment: стоит определиться - используешь ты angular или jquery

Comment: вместо использования jquery, надо было просто добавить [`ng-click`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClick) на нужный элемент

Comment: Но ведь в ng-click надо передать ссылку на элемент для того что бы откатиться до блока var block = $(this).parent().parent().find(".block-history-body"); Но передавая ng-click="clickBlock(this)" в функции честно говоря принимается не знаю что, но это точно не объект по которому кликали. Тут признаю, я не смог разобраться, знания JS у меня на уровне новичка и небольшое количество практики.

Comment: Тут не нужны знания js, тут нужно читать справку ангуляра. Основная проблема в том, что вместо стандартных средств написан костыль на jquery

Comment: Может быть поделитесь опытом? Я так понял событе на клик контролла нужно создать в контроллере, но вопрос как в функции полцчить ссылку на объект по которому кликнули, для того что бы от этого контролла можно было откатиться на два родителя назад и найти в данном блоке другой контрол и показать его? так как написано в коде.

Comment: на самом деле тебе не нужна ссылка на объект :-) это не jquery - ангуляр все сам делает, главное значения правильно расставь

Comment: при первой загрузке все элементы свернуты?